# Is it possible to use usemin with Jade templates?

Tags: pug, grunt-usemin

In my template, I have

```
//-<!-- build:css assets/app.css -->
link(href='public/stylesheets/override.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='public/stylesheets/base.css', rel='stylesheet')
//-<!-- endbuild -->
```

How can I run `usemin` via Grunt if I'm using Jade?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, I think it will solve your problem.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jade-usemin